# DBConnection Time Out Using SQL

Tags: c#, sql, database, timeout

I'm using C# to create simple application that will check the database repeatedly after 1 minutes. I'm using thread to make it more manner and reduce resources. These thread will executes one function only at one time in sync.

My problem is

> Exception was unhandled : DBConnection
>   Timeout expired. The timeout
>   period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is
>   not responding.

I understand that my connection with database exceed the time limit. So, how to solve this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using GDEX.Master;
using GDEX.DataAccess;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace SMPPTransfer
{
    public partial class frmDBTS : Form
    {
        string updateProbRecord = string.Empty;
        string selectProbRecord = string.Empty;
        string selectProbStat = string.Empty;
        string updateStat = string.Empty;
        string selectAssignTo = string.Empty;
        string CheckPODStatus = string.Empty;

        DataTable dtStat = null;
        DataTable dtPOD = null;
        DataTable dtAssignNo = null;

        bool stopThreads = false;
        AutoResetEvent blockThread1 = new AutoResetEvent(true);
        AutoResetEvent blockThread2 = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
        GDexSqlSvConnection dbCon;

        public frmDBTS()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            String connSQLSvr = "Data Source=<my IP>;Initial Catalog=<database>;User ID=<username>;Password=<pwd>;";
            dbCon = new GDexSqlSvConnection(connSQLSvr);

            Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(UpdateProbRec));
            Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(UpdateProbStat));

            thread1.Start();
            thread2.Start();
        }

        private void UpdateProbRec()
        {
            while (stopThreads == false)
            {
                blockThread1.WaitOne();

                SetText1("Entered Thread 1");
                SetText2("Out Thread 2");                

                //Get POD status
                CheckPODStatus = "select top 100 * from (select cn"
                                 + " FROM gdexpdb.dbo.prob_record where solve = 'N' and status!='S') A "
                                 + " join (select cn, cn_date"
                                 + " from gdexpdb.dbo.pod_data where type='rts' or type = 'pod' or type = 'm_pod' or type = 'm_rts') B "
                                 + "on A.CN=B.cn";

                dtPOD = dbCon.ExecuteQueryAndGetDataTable(CheckPODStatus); //Problem occur from here and only for this function only

                DateTime cnDate;
                string cnDateCon;
                for (int iii = 0; iii < dtPOD.Rows.Count; iii++)
                {
                    cnDate = (DateTime)dtPOD.Rows[iii][2];

                    cnDateCon = cnDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

                    updateProbRecord = "update gdexpdb.dbo.prob_record set solve='Y', solve_date='" + cnDateCon + "', status='S' "
                                        + "where cn='" + dtPOD.Rows[iii][0] + "'";
                    dbCon.ExecuteNonQuery(updateProbRecord);
                }

                dtPOD.Clear();
                Thread.Sleep(30000);
                blockThread2.Set();
            }
        }

        private void UpdateProbStat()
        {
            while (stopThreads == false)
            {
                blockThread1.WaitOne();

                SetText2("Entered Thread 2");
                SetText1("Out Thread 1");

                selectProbStat = "select username from gdexpdb.dbo.prob_stat";

                dtStat = dbCon.ExecuteQueryAndGetDataTable(selectProbStat);
                int[] userNo = new int[dtStat.Rows.Count];

                for (int x = 0; x < dtStat.Rows.Count; x++)
                {
                    selectAssignTo = "select count(*) as assignNo from gdexpdb.dbo.prob_record where assign_to='" + dtStat.Rows[x][0]+ "'";
                    dtAssignNo = dbCon.ExecuteQueryAndGetDataTable(selectAssignTo);

                    updateStat = "update gdexpdb.dbo.prob_stat set stat=" + dtAssignNo.Rows[0][0] + "where username='" + dtStat.Rows[x][0] + "'";
                    dbCon.ExecuteNonQuery(updateStat);
                }

                dtStat.Clear();
                dtAssignNo.Clear();
                Thread.Sleep(100000);
                blockThread1.Set();
            }
        }

        private void SetText1(string text)
        {
            // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
            // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
            // If these threads are different, it returns true.
            if (this.TextThread1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText1);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
            else
            {
                this.TextThread1.Text = text;
            }
        }

        private void SetText2(string text)
        {
            // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
            // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
            // If these threads are different, it returns true.
            if (this.TextThread2.InvokeRequired)
            {
                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText2);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
            else
            {
                this.TextThread2.Text = text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you already tried to do?

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: Show the code of GDexSqlSvConnection.ExecuteQueryAndGetDataTable()

Comment: I want to make auto execute function after (certain time that suit my database) 1 minute.

which line? when execute the query. I already put comment there.

Comment: Why are you sucking all the data off the server, simply to update it? You could do this two sql statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside `GDexSqlSvConnection` class - Functions `ExecuteQueryAndGetDataTable`, `ExecuteNonQuery` and others... Set `CommandTimeout` property to database command instances you are using to query database.

For Example:

```
MyCommand.CommandTimeout = 120; // 2 Minutes Timeout
```

Comment: Inside ExecuteQueryAndGetDataTable function

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a longer connection timeout in your connection string using the `Connect Timeout` property. Setting it to 0 means it will not timeout.

```
Connect Timeout=0
```

Refer: [Connection string options](http://www.connectionstrings.com/articles/show/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords)

Although, this will get you past your current problem, what you really need to do is fix your query.

**Simple selects and updates should not cause the database to timeout.**

To speed up those queries:

1. Create proper indexes on your tables
2. Partition your tables, use different file groups if they are very large.
3. Check the resource allocated to your database server.

Comment: The error he is getting is NOT caused by Connection's timeout but by Command timeout (the Error message is kind of wrong). Setting the Connection Timeout in Connection string would have no effect.

Comment: Still, his queries are pretty simple and should not timeout. Indexes, partitions and resource allocation done right would be better than increasing the `CommandTimeout`.

Comment: And this is not even narrow - every statement should execute in FAR less than a second. 1/100s of a second. Something is really at odds there - chance is no index or another very beginner mistake.

Comment: @nunespascal : what is default time out for 'CommandTimeout' and 'Connection Timeout'?

Comment: 'Connection Timeout' by default is 15 seconds(refer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and CommandTimeout be default is 30 seconds(refer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx).

Comment: String connSQLSvr = "Data Source=<ip address>, 1488;Initial Catalog=<database>;User ID=<username>;Password=<pwd>; Connect Timeout=0"; Same error occurs after using Connect Timeout

Answer (score 1):

The timeout can be eiter a ConnectionTimeout on your DbConnection or a CommandTimeout on DbCommand -- usually the last.

Answer (score 0):

I think this post can help you

[SQL Server Connection Timeout Expired](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/0ce80080-c503-4b51-b7a8-62b22a88ba8b)